# Use ffmpeg static and not binaries for Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, npm, ffmpeg

I am running a CentOS Linux server. I am trying to get ffmpeg to work on my discord bot. I have followed the guides using npm and switched `npm i ffmpeg-binaries` for `npm i ffmpeg-static` but it is still telling me that ffmpeg cannot be found.

Most of the answers I've looked at either resolve around using sudo, which is not an option here, or they are for windows based systems.

Comment: Not much to work with here. Where is the static ffmpeg installed? Where is the script/code/whatever looking for ffmpeg? Is the static ffmpeg in your `PATH`? Is the script utilizing your `PATH`? Can you not modify the script to provide the full path to the ffmpeg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realised that the reason that this wouldn't work was because the functionality had been blocked by the service provider. So after discussing this with then the issue has been solved.